# Accessing public assets from React JS application to other applciation

Tags: reactjs, cors

I have two `React JS` applications running on `3000` & `3001` locally and what I am, tring to do is, one application is having public asset (`/public`) i.e. json file which I can access like,

```
http://localhost:3000/styles.json
```

Other React JS application is tring to access it using axios as,

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/styles.json`)
```

But I am getting following error in console,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/styles.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Well this may not be right way but I want to know reason as what can I do to solve it or security violation it is linked with.

Reason I am trying this is, I have accessed one application in another using `iframe` with passing its own public folder json file path but another application failed to access it.

Comment: How can I use `proxy` here?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` or something?

Comment: @goto1 Yes but does it lead any strings here?

Comment: You will most likely have to eject your `create-react-app` and tweak with the `webpack-dev-server` configuration, but I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish by requesting the `styles.json` via `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) error you're seeing is because browsers won't load data from another domain (origin) by default.

In development you could get around this by using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/corsproxy which basically adds a header like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to requests proxied through it. In production, you'd need to get whatever server you're using to serve your `styles.json` asset to do the same: The * stops the browser complaining about it being on a different domain.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an answer to the question.

Comment: appreciated this which made sense, will try this one. Thanks!